# Is there some more detailed information about Dritok available?

Tags: unnatural-features, resource-request

[Dritok](http://content.time.com/time/arts/article/0,8599,1898948,00.html) is a conlang by Dan Boozer without any voiced sounds. It is said to be based on chipmunk sounds.

While this language even has a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dritok), I was not able to discover some more detailed information about the language like full phoneme inventory or some information about the transcription system used or some glossed examples of it.

Are there some resources on Dritok available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20110611070959/http://podcast.conlang.org/2009/02/dritok-the-sound-of-no-voice-speaking/) website contains a video and links to some resources. The most important is [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110725193552/http://conference.conlang.org/lcc2/LCC2_Program.pdf) PDF, which explains gestures ("Dritok Gestural Syntax"), phonology and grammar.

Comment: Great resource, the relevant info is on p. 18.